# jquery-ui-map or egeloen / IvoryGoogleMapBundle?

Tags: jquery-ui, google-maps, symfony

Which better to use **jquery-ui-map** or **egeloen / IvoryGoogleMapBundle**?

Thanks,

Comment: I don't really know both, but I can tell you that egeloen/Ivory ... are well known in Symfony's community and that if you use their bundles, you have not the responsability of integrating yourself a plugin ;). The less code to keep yourself, the easier to achive your objetives. So I'll say Ivory.

Comment: Good choice! I hope... :)

Comment: @egeloen: have you ever tried to intragate egeloen/IvoryGoogleMapBundle with the addresspicker.js?

Comment: Nope, but have you tried the built-in autocomplete form type?

Comment: @egeloen: not yet! Still new to IvoryGoogleMapBundle. If you have a good link on autocomplete form type, I will be happy!

Comment: The doc about the integration with the Symfony2 form component: https://github.com/egeloen/IvoryGoogleMapBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/usage/places/autocomplete.md

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to use IvoryGoogleMapBundle is you use symfony!